# bindingSource1.EndEdit() not saving to sql db

Tags: c#, sql

I've followed [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/using-bindingsource-class-in-ado-net/) example on C# Corner, my connection points to an existing sql db on server and bound my textboxes to the bindingsource. I can click next and previous ok and see the existing data, however I can't save any changes. My save button calls

```
bindingSource1.EndEdit();
```

if I restart the application it still has the old data and not save the change. Why might this be please, I've spent several hours searching and experimenting to no avail.

Edit:
I've now added events for bindingSource1 Current Changed & Binding complete, these events are happening as I next and prev and save, so binding is working and it knows that current has changed, but will not save.

Comment: after changing value in textbox please focus cursor on something else, and try to click the save button.

Comment: @ikram thanks, I clicked in the other text box and it did the same ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Adding this line after EndEdit()

```
YourTableAdapter.Update(YourDataSet.YourDB);
```

solves the problem, which is updating the dataset.